# Pip install requests error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'

Tags: python, linux, pip, archlinux

This is the error I get when I run `pip install requests` on Arch Linux:

````
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 248, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 77, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 369, in __init__
    max_retries=retries,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 26, in __init__
    super(CacheControlAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 310, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 180, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 77, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 369, in __init__
    max_retries=retries,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 26, in __init__
    super(CacheControlAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_retries'```
````

It gives the same error when I download the source code, and when I run as `sudo`.

Edit:

`pip --version` yields `pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Edit 2:

I was able to fix it by uninstalling the arch package `python-pip` and reinstalling it by downloading and running get-pip.py.

Comment: Edit your question to show the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: very strange .. seems that pip installation is broken .. did you test to install any other packages?

Comment: @BaleineBleue If you "Edit 2" solves the problem, the please post it as an answer and resolve the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by uninstalling the arch package python-pip and reinstalling it by downloading and running get-pip.py.